# Can't post message to slack through bot framework

Tags: rest, botframework, slack-api

I am trying to post a welcome message for new user.

Here is the request I received, when a user adds my bot to his/her slack group.

```
{
    "type":"installationUpdate",
    "id":"ID",
    "timestamp":"2018-01-06T14:41:32.4393782Z",
    "serviceUrl":"https:\/\/slack.botframework.com",
    "channelId":"slack",
    "from":{
        "id":"ID",
        "name":"Name"
    },
    "conversation":{
        "isGroup":false,
        "id":"ID:"
    },
    "recipient":{
        "id":"ID",
        "name":"Name"
    },
    "channelData":{
        "SlackMessage":{
            "type":"bot_added",
            "subtype":"none",
            "ts":"1515249692",
            "event_ts":"1515249692",
            "bot":{
                "id":"bot_id",
                "app_id":"app_id",
                "deleted":false,
                "name":"career_buddy"
            }
        },
        "ApiToken":"api token"
    },
    "action":"add"
}
```

If the request type is `installationUpdate`, I am posting my activity json object to the url `https://slack.botframework.com/v3/conversations/{ConversationID}/activities`.

Here is my activity json object

```
{
    "type":"message",
    "conversation":{
        "id":"ID:"
    },
    "recipient":{
        "id":"ID",
        "name":"name"
    },
    "from":{
        "id":"ID",
        "name":"name"
    },
    "channelId":"slack",
    "text":"Hello"
}
```

When I post it , I am getting 200 OK status.

But the response of that curl post is empty (`{}`), and also i am not getting any message in Slack.

Comment: Have you tried adding some text to your reply? "text": "reply to message"

Comment: @EricDahlvang : Thank you, After adding that I am getting 400 Bad Request error "Invalid or missing Activity in request"